# If loop in Bash not working

Tags: bash, installation

I have been working on an installer in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Are you sure you want to install the program installCMD? [y/n]"
answer="$@"
if [ $answer = "y" ] then
   echo "Installing Program installCMD"
   wget /usr/bin http://www.chronos.site90.net/DEV/installCMD 
else
   echo "Not installing program installCMD."
fi
```

Every time I run it it reads the error

```
Are you sure you want to install the program installCMD? [y/n]
installCMDInstaller: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
installCMDInstaller: line 7: `else'
```

Any help would be apreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to correct the first conditional part:

```
echo "Are you sure you want to install the program installCMD? [y/n]"
answer="$@"
if [ "$answer" == "y" ]; then
   echo "Installing Program installCMD"
   wget /usr/bin http://www.chronos.site90.net/DEV/installCMD 
else
   echo "Not installing program installCMD."
fi
```

Note the extra quotes and the semicolon after the test.

Comment: So you ask the user if he should install the program, but read the answer from the command line arguments. Shouldn't the `answer="$@"` be replaced with `read answer` or something?

Comment: @user000001 Probably; that's not the source of the error though.

Answer (score 1):

[Use More Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes):

```
if [ "$answer" = "y" ]
then
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there should be an ; after the if statement:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Are you sure you want to install the program installCMD? [y/n]"
answer="$@"
if [ $answer = "y" ]; then
   echo "Installing Program installCMD"
   wget /usr/bin http://www.chronos.site90.net/DEV/installCMD 
else
   echo "Not installing program installCMD."
fi
```

And i think you have to use == instead of =.